# Why is my for loop displaying the same item twice?

Tags: php, json

I am trying to display each item in a JSON array of reviews. There are two reviews in the array, but instead of displaying both of them, this code displays same one twice.

Why is this happening?

```
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$data = json_decode($response, true);

// Setup the Review for posting to the Mysql Database
// Loop through Reviews
for ($i=0; $i<count($data['reviews']); $i++) {
    $id = $data['reviews']['0']['id']; //  good
    $stars = $data['reviews']['0']['stars']; //good
    $title = $data['reviews']['0']['title'];
    $text = $data['reviews']['0']['text'];
    $createdAt = $data['reviews']['0']['createdAt'];
    $companyReply = $data['reviews']['0']['companyReply']['text'];
    $companyReplyDate = $data['reviews']['0']['companyReply']['createdAt'];

    // Do Mysql insert for each row

    // show this
    echo "id: " . $id . "</br>";
    echo "stars: " . $stars . "</br>";
    echo "title: " . $title . "</br>";
    echo "text: " . $text . "</br>";
    echo "Created: " . $createdAt . "</br>";
    echo "Reply: " . $companyReply . "</br>";
    echo "Reply Date: " . $companyReplyDate . "</br> </br>";
}

curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4):

It is because you aren't actually using your loop increment variable to get different array keys. You're just selecting the `['0']` index repeatedly. Instead, use `$i` as the array key like this:

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($data['reviews']); $i++) {
    $id = $data['reviews'][$i]['id']; //  good
    $stars = $data['reviews'][$i]['stars']; //good
    $title = $data['reviews'][$i]['title'];
    $text = $data['reviews'][$i]['text'];
    $createdAt = $data['reviews'][$i]['createdAt'];
    $companyReply = $data['reviews'][$i]['companyReply']['text'];
    $companyReplyDate = $data['reviews'][$i]['companyReply']['createdAt'];
    // ... etc.
```